# linearRegression coef results per line with R

Tags: r, linear-regression

Assume I use the following data

```
data(iris)
iris
```

And make the following regression:

```
linearReg <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length+Petal.Width, data=iris)
linearReg$coefficients

 (Intercept) Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
  4.1905824    0.5417772   -0.3195506
```

Now I would like to know how to use those coefficient result to **get the result for each 150 obs** of  my data iris.

- Line 1 : 4.1905824 + obs1_petal.lenght*0.5417772 +obs1_petal.width*-0.3195506
- Line 2 : 4.1905824 + obs2_petal.lenght*0.5417772 +obs2_petal.width*-0.3195506
- etc

Comment: Those aren't lines - those are just predictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `fitted.values` function:

```
predictions = fitted.values(linearReg)
```

This gives you a vector of length `150` with the prediction of each. For instance, `predictions[1]` is equal to `4.1905824 + iris$Petal.Length[1]*0.5417772 + iris$Petal.Width[1]*(-0.3195506)`.

If you wanted to do it manually, you could have done:

```
predictions =  4.1905824 + iris$Petal.Length*0.5417772 + iris$Petal.Width*(-0.3195506)
```

and you would have gotten the same value.

Comment: actually I just think your manual formula can also be : predictions <-  linearReg$coef[1]+ iris$Petal.Length linearReg$coef[2] + iris$Petal.Width*(linearReg$coef[3]) //

Comment: @Swiss12000: I know, I was just making it clearer since you put the raw numbers in the question.

Comment: OK thanks actually I just discovered it so maybe it will be usefull for someone who doesn't know :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `fitted` on the linear model object will get the predicted values for each observation

```
fitted(linearReg)
```

Alternatively you can use `predict` to plug in predictors to get predictions from a model.  In your case you could just plug in the original dataset.

```
 predict(linearReg, newdata = iris)
```

The difference here is that with predict you could get predictions for observations that weren't in the data set used to build your model.  For example if you wanted to make predictions for some new data you just need a data frame that contains a column for each of the predictors used in the model and then use that as the newdata parameter in predict

```
newdat <- data.frame(Petal.Length = c(1,2,3), Petal.Width = c(2,3,4))
predict(linearReg, newdata = newdat)
#       1        2        3 
#4.093258 4.315485 4.537712
```